# Problem defintion - canvases sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Could you please define possible even with screenshots what does it mean.

**Please make sure you canvases are sized to fit your artwork.**

What should be fixed?
Thank you

Comment: The solution is you fix everything, make it fit on the canvas artwork, then take a screenshot, so then by definition the problem is solved.

Comment: I cannot understand expression “canvas artwork” in context of photoshop. What does it mean? Layers, artboards or what?

Answer (score 0):

Explained at [Extropedia](http://www.extropia.com/tutorials/photoshop/drawing_canvas.html) the canvas is:

> The drawing canvas is the area in which you will create and/or modify images. By default, Photoshop gives you a drawing canvas to work with, but you can easily open another one by using the "New" menu choice from the "File" menu item.

As for sizing the canvas to your artwork, I recommend you use the "trim" command which is demonstrated in [this walkthrough](https://tutvid.com/photoshop-tutorials/canvas-size-expanding-your-psd/):

> There are also options under the Image menu “Trim” and “Reveal All”. Trim allows you to quickly trim away transparent pixels from your image to get only used bits for your final image export. Reveal all will automatically expand the canvas of your PSD to show any graphics that are “sticking off” of the canvas area.